# AutoMapper map source property into inner destination object

Tags: automapper

I have one source class:

```
class Source {
    public string Name;
    public string Field1;
    public string Field2;
}
```

and two destination classes:

```
class Destination {
    public string Name;
    public FieldsDto Fields;
}

class FieldsDto {
    public string Field1;
    public string FieldTwo;
}
```

How can I map `Source.Field1` to `Destination.Fields.Field1` and `Source.Field2` to `Destination.Fields.FieldTwo`?

This code does not work; it would throw an error saying that `Custom configuration for members is only supported for top-level individ
ual members on a type1`:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
    cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Fields.Field1, opt => opt.Mapfrom(src => src.Field1)
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Fields.FieldTwo, opt => opt.Mapfrom(src => src.Field2);
});
```

Comment: Use ForPath instead.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Could you elaborate?

Comment: Not really, just search previous answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, in order to map nested properties, you will need to use `ForPath` instead of `ForMember`. So a full configuration may look like this:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Name))
        .ForPath(dest => dest.Fields.Field1, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Field1))
        .ForPath(dest => dest.Fields.FieldTwo, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Field2));
});
```

If you want to do this dynamically, using member names as string (which appears like something you want to do, as I learned in chat), then you will not be able to use `ForPath` easily since that absolutely requires a lambda expression that contains only a member expression.

What you *could* do is create a lambda expression dynamically for the nested member access. I’m sure you will find enough examples on how to create such lambda expressions on here if you search for it.

The alternative would be to split up the mapping into the separate types. So instead of mapping directly to nested properties of the `Destination`, you are mapping the nested object separately. Like this:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Source, FieldsDto>()
        .ForMember("Field1", opt => opt.MapFrom("Field1"))
        .ForMember("FieldTwo", opt => opt.MapFrom("Field2"));
    cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Name))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Fields, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => Mapper.Map<FieldsDto>(s)));
});
```